# Google sheet query across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 4 tabs called

hoses intercooler pipeworkCNC others

i am trying to search all sheets returning if anything searched for is found in column A

I have tried the following

=QUERY({hoses!A2:G3000; intercooler!A2:G3000; pipeworkCNC!A2:G3000; Others!A2:G3000},"select * where (lower(A) contains lower('"&B2&"'))")

but it returns error saying NO COLUMN A

I know i have to reference the sheet and column in the select * where (lower(A) part of query i was thinking along the lines of

select * where (lower(hoses!A) or (lower(intercooler!A) etc but this does not work

Can anyone help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not a range but an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), so you will have to use `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3` instead of `A`, `B`, `C`, like this:

```
=query( 
  { 
    hoses!A1:G; 
    intercooler!A2:G; 
    pipeworkCNC!A2:G; 
    Others!A2:G 
  },
  "where lower(Col1) contains '" & lower(B2) & "' ", 
  1 
)
```